# Running IBM DOORS in a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've managed to install IBM DOORS 9 in a container and this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rational/doors:2.2
ENV REFRESHED_AT 27-03-2017

RUN yum install -y -q libstdc++.so.6 libuuid.so.1
RUN export DOORSHOME=/ibm/rational/doors/9.6.1.6/DOORS_Database_Server
RUN export SERVERDATA=/ibm/rationa/doors/data
RUN export PATH=$DOORSHOME/bin:$PATH
RUN export PORTNUMBER=36677
RUN export DOORSHOME SERVERDATA PATH PORTNUMBER DOORSDATA

EXPOSE 36677

WORKDIR /ibm/rational/doors/9.6.1.6/DOORS_Database_Server/bin
ENTRYPOINT ./doorsd
```

However, if I try to run  it

```
docker run -d -p 36677  rational/doors:2.4
```

it exists after a couple of seconds

```
docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
4a0b77173531        rational/doors:2.4   "/bin/bash"         7 seconds ago       Exited (0) 6 seconds ago                       festive_lovelace
```

What am I missing here? If I run the container manually everything works perfectly.

Comment: Do not use export, the ENV directive of à Dockerfile is designed for

Comment: Post `docker logs a40`

Comment: As you have several RUN, I guess your export are "lost"

Comment: To emphasize what @user2915097 said: those `RUN export ...` comands, they do nothing.

Comment: No, they do nothing.  Try it.  One one line put a `RUN export FOO=bar`, and then on the next line put an `RUN echo $FOO`, and I *guarantee* you will find the variable unset.  A `RUN` command is an isolated shell, and variables defined and/or exported there will not be visible in other `RUN` commands or in the container when it runs.

Comment: Replace all your `RUN export` b'y `ENV` , rebuild and retry

Comment: OK I will try @larsks.

Comment: So is my understanding  of the semantic of ENV wrong?

Comment: Thanks it works!

Comment: So you replaced all your `RUN export` by `ENV` (except the last one), and it works?